# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "RangeError: Invalid array length" [Vue JS]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am attempting to play with the sample of vue.js poker sample available here - https://codepen.io/Rovak/pen/ExYeQar 
The HTML looks like

```
<div class="card-place">
        <card v-for="(card, index) in tableCards" :card="card"></card>
</div>
```

Initial data of Vue JS looks like

```
let app = new Vue({
el: '.vue-container',
data: {
    player_playing: 0,
    playerCards: [],
    tableCards: [],
    players: [],.....},...
})
```

Initially the `tableCards` is empty, whenever I am receiving data via websockets, I am updating the `tableCards` using the below method

```
function placeTableCards(cardsOnTable) {
    app.tableCards = cardsOnTable
}
```

where cardsOnTable is an array of cards object.

On updation I am getting an error as follows

```
vue.js:1897 RangeError: Invalid array length
```

I am extremely new to VueJS and stuck on this for long. Any help will be highly appreciated. Do let me know if you need more data from my end.

Comment: This error usually means you have an array with a negative length set or too big length.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a reactivity error.

You are trying to `onload` loop over an array that has nothing in it. Its NULL.

What you want to do is wrap your for-loop in an if statement to make sure its only run when data is actually present:

```
<div class="card-place" v-if="tableCards">
        <card v-for="(card, index) in tableCards" :card="card"></card>
</div>
```

Or you can initialize your `TableCards` with something in it, but utilizing vueJs's reactivity engine would be preferable.

Once placeTableCards() is run, Vuejs should pick up on the data change, the if-statement will pass true, and your loop should execute.

Comment: This doesn't help...Still throwing the same error :( ...I even tried updating every value via app.$set(app.tableCards, 0, card)....Even that doesn't help

Comment: run this function in a beforeCreate() ```function placeTableCards(cardsOnTable) {
    app.tableCards = cardsOnTable
}``` Also, you need a :key bind on your for-loop, add this to it `:key="index"`